# Replace single entity in query cache from JPA/Hibernate/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, eclipselink

We need to cache the results of a query; the query returns the whole table of a database. The problem is that the database is changed externally by other application; the Java application making the query is notified with the exact primary key of the row changed.

Is it possible to replace only the changed element from the query cache, not the whole list?
Is this the 1st level cache (from EntityManager) 2nd level Cache (from EntityManagerFactory) or a different cache?

If it is possible can this be done from JPA?

```
entityManager.refersh(entity);
```

or is this query cache the 2nd level JPA cache:

```
entityManagerFactory.getCache().evict(cls, primaryKey);
```

or only possible through Hibernate/EclipseLink API?

If is not possible, in order to achieve this, would calling `entityManager.find()` on all elements do it?

I haven't find anything useful neither in [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) nor in [EclipseLink documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache). Hibernate supports regions and refreshing only regions, but we need entity-level refresh granularity.

---

Later edit to clarify my findings.

Following the link posted by @Chris in the comment I have found out that what I wanted is actually [supported by EclipseLink](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/DatabaseEvents) but only for Oracle Database (there is possible to implement own handler for other vendors; but the call from database is not standardized and differs from vendor to vendor). I have not found if Hibernate supports this or not.

Anyhow the query cache from EclipseLink had some very poor performance compared with Spring Cache (based on CocurrentMap) or with custom based cache so will remain with Spring Cache or Custom Cache over Spring Jdbc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityManager.refresh() is what you want - it refreshes the entity from what is in the database.  This should also update the entity in the shared cache if you are not in a transaction, otherwise you may need to use the entityManagerFactory.getCache().evict(cls, primaryKey); as well to clear the second level shared cache so it can be read into it as well later on.

Comment: So query cache is not a separate cache?

Comment: A query cache isn't a part of JPA, so you would have to had configured it specific to your provider - EclipseLink's query cache isn't on by default, and only applies to a query's results, not the data returned.  So as long as the query returns the same entities, invalid entities should be picked up from the database.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that the docs imply the invalid entities should get refreshed from the database.  If changes affect the query results that would be returned (the IDs, not the raw entity data values), you would need to invalidate your query cache.  In EclipseLink 2.5 this changed so that invalidating entities automatically invalidated queries using those entities: http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/06/cool-performance-features-of.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments; from the blog post, it mentions that it is possible but it does it automatically only with Oracle database; otherwise an interface is needed to be implemented. Do you know somehow if Hibernate also has this functionality?